testcontainer will not start but image works
I have a local docker repository which contains my app deployed in a image.
I can pull that image from my container with docker pull localhost:6000/demo_code_image
and create a container with docker run and run my cucumber test against it.
But if I try with a Tescontainers GenericContainer I get errors:
Container startup failed for image localhost:6000/demo_code_image:latest
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed for  image localhost:6000/demo_code_image:latest
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:359)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:330)
at coding.example.e2e.LoginTest.setupClass(LoginTest.java:37)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:344)
... 4 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:563)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:354)
at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (127.0.0.1 ports: [32788, 32789] should be listening)
at         org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HostPortWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HostPortWaitStrategy.java:112)
at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:52)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:909)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:500)
... 7 more

I have tried google searching and various ways to start the container using the @Container annotation in a static  etc.
Every way I have tried get exactly the same result!
I know the image and the repository work because from command line I can pull and run.
Must be doing something stupid, cant even get a different error!

Did you look at the container logs? Also, your question doesn't include enough information to reproduce your problem. Might want to edit it.

The container does not start, no logs I have no other information. Have read through the Testcontainer docs and tried all the methods from the examples I could find. Every version fails with the same error. Looks like it cant pull from the local repository but tested that and works OK. Even tried from the Docerfile but that also fails. Looking for inspiration on where to check next

new error: org/apache/commons/codec/Charsets
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/Charsets
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:212)
.....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.Charsets
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
... 25 more

So what you'll want to do is create a small demo project. This project should contain the the problem and only the problem. Then you put that information in your question. This is work, quite a lot of it sometimes, but either you'll find the problem by doing this or you'll have everything you need for someone else to help you.

Right now I'm guessing your dependencies are inconsistent, and you can debug that with mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose. But I don't even know if you are using Maven.

The solution was to change the detection of the container ready.
It was starting but not being detected.
.waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".Started Application.", 1))
solved the issue.
